# How to apply 'as.numeric' to 'digit' character vectors, and let 'alpha' vecors intact

Tags: r

I have character numbers and character words in my datatable. I'm trying to change character numbers into 'numeric' and let other character words intact. And don't know how to.

```
X<-matrix(c('a','b','c','1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3'),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(X)<-c('A','B','C')
```

Let's make a DT like this. a,b,c on the top row, and digits below them. Now I'm trying to let this first row intact and apply as.numeric to only the 2~4 rows where digits with commas belongs.

I tried codes like

1) `X[,1]<-as.numeric(grep("[[:digit:]]",X[,1]))`

2) `as.numeric(X,pattern="\\d",na.rm=TRUE)`

And tried to make function like

3)

```
ASN<-function(X){
  if(ls(X, pattern = "\\d"))
    as.numeric(X)
  return(x)
}
```

And it all failed. They just don't work or putting out tables like `[Na, 1,2,3 ...]`. What can I do further?

Comment: It isn't possible to have a column of a matrix/data frame with more than one type.  If you have a column consisting of text all of which can be converted into numbers, then we can help you.